# How do I align the row height of resource column and events column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I'm working on KendoUI Scheduler for my current project and when I added the image in resource column of the scheduler, I faced a row height mismatched problem. The height of the resource cell is not getting same as the height of the scheduler slot.

I have tried to achieve this by setting the height using CSS but no luck.

```
$(function () {
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
        date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
        startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
        height: 600,
        eventHeight: 10,
        majorTick: 60,
        RowHeight: 300,
        //slotTemplate: "<div style='background:#=getColorBasedOnHour(date, JSON.stringify(data))#; height: 100%;width: 100%;'></div>",
        views: [ {
            type: "timelineMonth",
            //type: "kendo.ui.TimelineNoGap",
            //type: "kendo.ui.DayViewNoGap",
            title: "TimelineMonth",
            startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 00:00 AM"),
            majorTick: 1440
        }, 
        "timelineWorkWeek", "timelineWeek", {
          //type: "kendo.ui.DayViewNoGap",
          minorTickCount: 4,
          type: "kendo.ui.TimelineView",
          //type: "timeline",
          title: "Timeline",

        }
        ],
        timezone: "Etc/UTC",
        dataSource: {
            batch: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                update: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/update",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                create: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/create",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                destroy: {
                    url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/destroy",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
                },
                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "meetingID",
                    fields: {
                        meetingID: { from: "MeetingID", type: "number" },
                        title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                        start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                        end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                        startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                        endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                        description: { from: "Description" },
                        recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                        recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                        recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                        roomId: { from: "RoomID", nullable: true },
                        attendees: { from: "Attendees", nullable: true },
                        isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        group: {
            resources: ["Attendees"],
            orientation: "vertical"
        },
        groupHeaderTemplate: $("#groupHeaderTemplate").html(),
        resources: [

            {
                field: "attendees",
                name: "Attendees",
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398", image: "http://localhost:8080/car-rent-app/kendo/examples/content/chat/Doctor2.jpg" },
                    { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed", image: "http://localhost:8080/car-rent-app/kendo/examples/content/chat/Doctor3.jpg" },
                    { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85", image: "http://localhost:8080/car-rent-app/kendo/examples/content/chat/Doctor4.jpg" }
                ],
                multiple: true,
                title: "Attendees"
            }
        ],
        slotTemplate: "<div style='background:#=getColorBasedOnHour(date, JSON.stringify(event))#; height: 100%;width: 100%;'></div>"
    });



<style>

.k-scheduler-timelineWeekview .k-scheduler-table td, 
.k-scheduler-timelineview tr:nth-child(2) .k-scheduler-table td,
.k-scheduler-timelineview tr:nth-child(2) .k-scheduler-table th,
.k-scheduler-timelineWorkWeekview .k-scheduler-table td,
.k-scheduler-timelineMonthview .k-scheduler-table td {
    height: 71px !important;
}


</style>
```

[image: See the mismatched row height]

Comment: It may be that fixed height 71px. Why not remove it and align top with CSS?

Comment: I have to set the height to 71px that's why it has the fixed height. The height is not reducing from 86px.